# ECMAScript Client OM with External List

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, javascript, client-object-model

In SharePoint 2010, for a regular "custom" list calling SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems() using the ECMAScript client object model returns an array of item IDs. These IDs correspond to the SPListItem.ID property of the server object model.

Using the same approach for an external (BCS) list, getSelectedItems() is returning IDs of the form "_*bg40001300", "*_bg40002300", "__bg40003300", etc... My application is passing these IDs as HTTP paramters to the server where the server OM is using them to try and access the selected SPListItems. Is there some way to access the selected SPListItem's using this strange ID, either by converting it into a standard list item ID, or using a different API method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got any answer for this??? I am also in the same situation, trying to get the BCS List Item values in Server Side.

Comment: I discovered that it is possible to access the BCS list item using the ID by making a CAML query against the "BdcIdentity" field. This is the field that contains the "_bg4000xxxx" value.

Comment: Also, MSDN has some information on this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464402.aspx. They don't use a CAML query, though. I suppose the approach you take should depend on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @jason.venema Maybe you could post your solution in a new answer and accept it? That way it will be in an answer instead of comments. :)